# Is it really more efficient to WhenAll() on a number of tiny awaitable methods?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-6.0

Given an external API method signature like the following:

`Task<int> ISomething.GetValueAsync(int x)`

I often see code such as the following:

```
public async Task Go(ISomething i)
{
    int a = await i.GetValueAsync(1);
    int b = await i.GetValueAsync(2);
    int c = await i.GetValueAsync(3);
    int d = await i.GetValueAsync(4);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{a} - {b} - {c} - {d}");
}
```

In code reviews it is sometimes suggested this is inefficient and should be rewritten:

```
public async Task Go(ISomething i)
{
    Task<int> ta = i.GetValueAsync(1);
    Task<int> tb = i.GetValueAsync(2);
    Task<int> tc = i.GetValueAsync(3);
    Task<int> td = i.GetValueAsync(4);
    
    await Task.WhenAll(ta,tb,tc,td);
    int a = ta.Result, b= tb.Result, c=tc.Result, d = td.Result;
    Console.WriteLine($"{a} - {b} - {c} - {d}");
}
```

I can see the logic behind allowing parallelisation but in reality is this worthwhile? It presumably adds some overhead to the scheduler and if the methods themselves are very lightweight, it seems likely that thread parallelisation would be more costly than the time saved. Further, on a busy server running many applications, it seems unlikely there would be lots of cores sitting idle.

I can't tell if this is always a good pattern to follow, or if it's an optimisation to make on a case-by-case basis? Do Microsoft (or anyone else) give good best practice advice? Should we *always* write `Task` - based code in this way as a matter of course?

Comment: Scheduler overhead is generally a non-issue if gains can be made from parallelization, which is the main concern. If such gains *can't* be made, then no, but that would be unusual. Keep in mind that async != parallel; it's possible that even 100 asynchronous requests could be executing on the system in parallel with no processor overhead at all (that only comes when the results need to be gathered, but that overhead is easily dwarfed by the runtime gains). For an external API you're more likely to want explicit control over the degree of parallelism, for example with `Parallel.ForEachAsync`.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` returns a `Task<T[]>` if all tasks have the same return value. You could write `var ints=await Task.WhenAll(i.Get(), i.Get(),..)`. Or `var ints=await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(i.GetvalueAsync));` Does it matter though? If you call another service, can it handle concurrent calls or will this result in increased blocking?

Comment: What is the expected average duration of an `await GetValueAsync()` operation?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias this is a made-up example. That's my whole question, when should(n't) I do this? Or should I always as good practice and let the runtime decide what to do?

Answer (score 2):

> if the methods themselves are very lightweight, it seems likely that thread parallelisation would be more costly than the time saved.

This is definitely an issue with *parallel* code (the parallel form of concurrency), but this is *asynchronous* concurrency. Presumably, `GetValueAsync` is a true asynchronous method, which generally implies I/O operations. And I/O operations tend to dwarf many local considerations. (Side note: the `WhenAll` approach actually causes *fewer* thread switches and *less* scheduling overhead, but it does increase *memory* overhead slightly).

So, this is a win in the general case. However, that does assume that the statements above are correct (i.e., `GetValueAsync` performs I/O).

As a contrary point, however, I have seen this sometimes used as a band-aid for an inadequate data access layer. If you're hitting a *SQL database* with four queries, then the best solution is usually to combine that data access into a single query rather than do four calls to the same SQL database concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

First, what does `await` [actually](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5lQDMmM6AwugN7Lq2bFQAcmAbOgLIAUAlFTXQKgBOVgDoAmgEsApgBtgPfEgEBfZCqA=) do?

```
public async Task M() {
    await Task.Yield();
}
```

If the awaitable object has already completed, then execution continues immediately. Otherwise a callback delegate is added to the awaitable object. This callback will be invoked *immediately* when the task result is made available.

So what about `Task.WhenAll`, how does that work? The current implementation adds a callback to every incomplete task. That callback will decrement a counter atomically. When the counter reaches zero, the result will be made available.

No new I/O is scheduled, no continuations added to the thread pool. Just a small counter added to the end of each tasks processing. Your continuation will resume on whichever thread executed the last task.

If you are measuring a performance problem. I wouldn't worry about the overheads of `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: The `await Task.Yield()` might not be the best example, because is returns a specialized awaitable that is always incomplete. `await Task.Delay(1)` might be a better example, because there is a chance that the `awaiter.IsCompleted` is actually true.

Comment: I only needed an example of how `await` is turned into IL by the C# compiler. The type of awaitable doesn't matter for this example.